# Icons too small in 7'' tablet

Tags: android, icons, screen-resolution

I'm working on an application and I've received a complaint from a user that the interface is tremendously small. Although in all the devices I have tested (including tablets) the interface is displayed correctly, in his (Samsung Galaxy Tab A 7'') effectively the icons are disproportionately small.

It is as if Android is selecting the HDPI icons for this tablet.

Table cell in normal device:
[image]

Table cell in this tablet:
[image]

I can see it even happens with some texts. Have anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: For 7' Inches of tablet, i created folder in drawable as `drawable-large` and i placed my png and svg images in that.

Comment: @Android And the 7' tablets will automatically select the icons from that folder? Or do I have to make some extra configuration?

Comment: Icons will shows up based on default `drawable`, but we have to define for specific screens like `large`, `xlarge`, `small` like this. So that it will takes up an icon from appropriate folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tablets, you should provide separate drawable images. 
Create your drawables and put them in

**For 7-inch tablet (hdpi and tvdpi density)**

> res -> drawable-large

or

> res -> drawable-sw600

**For 10-inch tablet (mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi density)**

> res -> drawable-xlarge

or

> res -> drawable-sw800

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and come back with the answer.